# Using scipy in python apache beam on GCP Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, scipy, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a pipeline written in python apache beam and have written some code in it to use scipy. When I deploy it I see the following issue:

> numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries
> found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because you have two missing libraries in your python project.

Run the next command to install them.

```
conda install -c conda-forge liblapack
```